# What is wrong with my for-loop?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, while-loop, boolean

```
public class Lockers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean[] lockers = new boolean[100];
        int num = 2;
        for(int a=0; a < 100; a++) {
            lockers[a] = true;
        }

        for(int num=1; num < 101; num++) {

            for(int i=1; i < 100; i = i+num) {
                if (lockers[i]) {
                lockers[i] = false;
                    }
                else {
                    lockers[i] = true;
                    }
        }}

        for(int i=0; i < 100; i++) {
            if (lockers[i]) {
                System.out.print("Opened");
                }
            else {
                System.out.print("Closed");
                }
        }

}}
```

So this program is out of my java textbook for school, the idea is there are 100 lockers all open now starting at the second locker close every 2nd one. (2,4,6,8,10) Then restarting at the second locker go through with every 3rd locker doing the same (opening a closed locker, or closing an open one). Now my third for-loop seems to be my issue it will not function for some reason, the second for-loop is included so when the third for-loop starts it goes through every 2nd locker then back to the second for-loop statement it increases "num" by 1 goes through ever 3rd then 4th and so on and so forth. i would like to  only use the basic commands i have learned so far in java and in the program now, so please help me solve this problem without really advanced coding.

The problem is that when i run the program the third for-loop is an infinite loop, i know the first two loops run fine, i tested that by after the second for-loop i made it output the "num" and it outputs all numbers 2 through 100 like i want but then the loop is endless at the third for-loop, not outputting anything else

Comment: "_it will not function_" Elaborate. Wrong output? Exceptions? Show some examples of expected output vs. actual output. Also, please try to use actual sentences because as it is now it is hard to read that and understand what you are talking about.

Comment: You never do the loop with `num==2`.

Comment: issue is at `int i=1` that makes you loop through indexes 1,3,5.. (second, forth, so far so good) and then indexes 1,4... (second, fifth). You probably want `int i = num - 1`

Comment: Actually, it's the first iteration that closes the second, fifth, eighth etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it as simple as:

for(int i=0; i < 100; i = i++)

should be:

for(int i=0; i < 100; i++)

Comment: Yeah, I don't know.  I didn't downvote it.  I'm sure those who did have their reasons.

Comment: That actually works, thank you so much! i do not quite understand why it does not work with the i = i++ but still i thank you, i dont know why your being voted down since your the only one to solve the problem

Comment: I removed my comment about only finding one of the three bugs, since Nick's edit to the question indicates that he is only asking about this bug, not the other two.  So this answer is correct (and so is Tomer_Zabo1802's answer).

Comment: David Wallace, can you tell me the other two bugs that you see? My program seems to work fine right now i believe. my output may still be incorrect im not sure

Answer (score 1):

I am not so good wtih java, so I will tell you what I think from my knowlage at C#.

In your last for loop you are writing `i=i++`,
what you need to write is this: `i=i+1`

this is what i think .... try that tell me if that works for you

Comment: i thought i++ was the same as i+1?

Comment: i++ is same as i+1. But when you say i = i+1. It will be evaluated like below.
int tmp = i;
i = i+1;
i = tmp;
that's why your i will be always 0.

Comment: Yes. That's why instead of `i = i++` you should just use `i++` alone. @NickJones I thought the same at first but then ran a couple of tests and found my intuition was wrong.

Comment: Thank you very much, i did not see that error till now.